# What does こんくらいのほう mean, in this sentence?

Tags: expressions, abbreviations

> まーな、こんくらいのほうが野菜の味がわかんだろ

I know it's the abbreviation of これくらいのほう, but what does it mean exactly?

Comment: こんくらい -> これくらい, ほうが: https://takoboto.jp/bunpo/786

Comment: I've made a mistake, I've changed it. Thank you. Also, I've removed the last question. I know what ほうが mean, I should have known the answer.

Comment: 「これくらい」、「このくらい」・・・どっちもおんなじなのでは・・

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without くらい, it becomes このほうが = *in this way (rather than other ways of cooking)*. Although some more contexts are necessary for a precise translation, but the speaker should be saying that the current way of cooking is better in that one can taste the natural flavor of vegetables (while it would not remain by other more sophisticated ways of cooking).

くらい makes the expression less direct, so that こんくらいのほうが would translate as *like this way (compared with others)*.

Comment: 「野菜の切り方がなんというか･･････」, this is what the other character says before. So, it's the way of cutting. Is "approximately in this way" a fine translation too?

Comment: @Haragurodanshi To my non-native ears it sounds a bit unusual, but should be fine as long as it is fine as English. The idea is that くらい indicates there are other possible ways than *this way* to make the vegetables taste better. Another literal translation would be *in this kind of way of cutting*.